# JQuery: How to correct this Add New Table Row Function

Tags: jquery

I have this html table and want tried to write Add new row function for it Using Jquery.But it is not working.
Here is sample Jquery code:

```
$('tr td input[type="checkbox"].yes').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find(":input:not(.yes)").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    $(this).closest('tr').find(":input.no").prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
$(".addmore").click(function() {
    var data = "<tr><td><input class='yes' type='checkbox' checked/></td><td><input type='text' value='4444'/></td><td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td><td><input type='text' value='DDDD'/></td><td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td></tr>";
    $('table').append(data);
});
```

Here is the link given bellow:

[jsfiddle Source Code Link](https://jsfiddle.net/gc249L9g/2/)

Please help.Thanks

Comment: You don't add `jquery` plugin to your demo.

Comment: Does your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for adding rows in table by clicking add more button. Here is working code for adding rows in table.

```js
$(".addmore").click(function(){
    var data= "<tr><td><input class='yes' type='checkbox'/></td><td><input type='text' value=''/></td><td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td><td><input type='text' value=''/></td><td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td></tr>"; 
  $('table tbody').append(data);      
});

$('tr td input[type="checkbox"].yes').change( function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find(":input:not(.yes)").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
   $(this).closest('tr').find(":input.no").prop('checked', !this.check);
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
}

table, th, td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Enable/Disable</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>textinput</th>
    <th>Select 2</th>
  </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="yes" type="checkbox" checked/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="1111"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="AAAAA"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="yes" type="checkbox" checked/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2222"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="BBBB"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="yes" type="checkbox" checked/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3333"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="CCCC"/></td>
    <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class='addmore'>+ Add More</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Mohammad pointed out, you didn't add JQuery to your jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gc249L9g/4/

It's working now for me.

[image]

```
 some "code" so I can post this
```

Answer (score 1):

did you take a look at this site ? http://jshint.com/